# Calling a Stored Procedure in Postgresql From JAVA without any return

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a SP in **postgresql** database, which saves/updates USER specific data for a system.
The SP doesn't return anything when it is called.

Now from Java I am trying to call the SP , however I am confused about the return value.

My Code :

```
        Connection conn = DatabaseConnection.connect();
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("call public.spsaveuser (?,?,?,?,?);");
        // CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{CALL public.spsaveuser (?,?,?,?,?) }");


        stmt.setString(1, userName);
        stmt.setString(2, someString);
        stmt.setString(3, anotheString);
        stmt.setBoolean(4, someBoolean);
        stmt.setInt(5, someIntegerVal);

        
        int numColsAffected = stmt.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("numColsAffected : " + numColsAffected);
        
        return (numColsAffected > 0);
```

I always get this `numColsAffected`  as 0 however in the Database the tables gets updated.

So what return type can I compare here in my case to confirm Success / Failure

**UPDATE**

According to this [sql server doc](https://www.sqlshack.com/using-stored-procedures-with-return-values/)

***Return Value in SQL Server Stored Procedure***

> In default, when we execute a stored procedure in SQL Server, it
> returns an integer value and this value indicates the execution status
> of the stored procedure. The 0 value indicates, the procedure is
> completed successfully and the non-zero values indicate an error. The
> following query will create a very simple stored procedure to get
> departments’ information. Let’s understand this concept better with an
> example.

And according to [Postgresql doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xproc.html)  there is no such definite return mentioned.

Comment: I don't think `executeUpdate()` will return the number of affected rows (not columns btw) if the UPDATEs are "hidden" behind a stored procedure. You would either need to use a function that returns the number of affected rows or use an `OUT` parameter in your stored procedure.

Comment: Would you please post your stored procedure 'spsaveuser' ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : You are right , I think we need to use some return on condition inside the SP to the ```OUT``` and then we can compare.

Comment: @HamzaKhadhri : It is very big doing lots of stuffs creating temp table here and there and then inserting or updating the db tables.